# Azure AD App Manifest - Added Users will have "Approles.value", groups don't

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, adal

We have created an Application in the Azure AD and so far everything works fine.
We have two roles defined in the Manifest AppUser & AppAdmin

If i add an ADUser to the Applicaton as AppUser, the jwt token will have the value "AppUser" -> so far so good, works as expected.

The Problem starts, when adding a Group, where the ADUser is member of. The JWT Token won't have the value "AppUser" anymore.

```
    appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "User"
            ],
            "description": "Standard user can see basic information",
            "displayName": "AppUser",
            "id": "--------------",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "User"
        },
#
#
# some other values
#
#
"groupMembershipClaims": "ApplicationGroup",
```

Is this by design, or is the Manifest wrongly configured?
We are using Adal as a library.

Answer (score 0):

So,

after investigation and doing a lot of test we found out, that the user inheritance only works on the top level application group.

In our example we had within the Application two usertypes:

- User
- Admin

So we added a group called **app-users** to the application in the Azure AD and gave the the right "User". As long as a *ADUser* was added by name driectly to the "app-users" *ADGroup* everything was fine. But if we added another *ADGroup*- __coolAPPUsergrou__p - to the existing "app-users", all the users within the "**coolAPPUsergroup**" won't have the application value "User" in the jwt Token.
The reason is, that inheritance is not working in this case.

To solve the problem we added the *ADGroup* **coolAPPUsergroup** directly to the application - on the same level as **app-users** - and tada -> works like a charm.

I would recommend to do this management within the Azure Cloud Portal, because you will get an error regarding inheritance. If you do that on your local AD, it is perfectly finde to add a group to the exiting AppADGroup, but it won't work.